# Make served Jekyll project accessible within local network

Tags: jekyll

I'm creating a website locally with Jekyll from my desktop Linux. It's connected to the same router as my other devices, I would like to test the site directly from my android but it's inaccessible.

I also tried to serve the `_site` directory with `darkhttpd` and it works, I can access it from  android. Is there a way to do that with only Jekyll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by starting the server with this:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

You can then access the site locally by going to the servers IP and port 4000. It might look similar to this:

```
http://192.168.1.100:4000
```

Source: https://zarino.co.uk/post/jekyll-local-network/

Comment: Why, thank you good sir. Also, the IP can be seen with `ifconfig`. In my case its 192.168.0.7.